# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray while i retrive data from MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have made an php code to get the array of data from MYSQL but now i am struggling to get it back to my android

php code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $user_tags = array();

    foreach ($_REQUEST['user_id'] as $key => $val) {
        $user_tags[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    $user_ids = "'" . implode("','", $user_tags) . "'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tags WHERE user_id IN ({$user_ids})";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();
    //looping through all the records fetched

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        $result['tags'][] = $row['tags'];   
    }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

This gives the result:{"result":{"tags":["Pascol","PHP","Python"]}}

when I try to toast "tags" in my android I get this error:

```
    rg.json.JSONException: Value {"tags":["Pascol","PHP","Python"]} at result       of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

My android code:

```
  public class Jobs extends AppCompatActivity {
   public static final String DATA_URL =    "http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Sort.php?work[]=";
public static String tags="";

private String JSON_STRING;
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
public static final String KEY_USER_TAGS="tags";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jobs);

    getEmployee();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tags,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    check();

}

    private void getEmployee(){
    class GetEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(Jobs.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            showEmployee(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Config.URL_GET_TAG,UserAreaActivity.id);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetEmployee ge = new GetEmployee();
    ge.execute();
}

private void showEmployee(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
       String ttags = c.getString(KEY_USER_TAGS);
        tags=ttags.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the response is coming as a JSONObject. You are trying to convert that to JSONArray.

Try this,

```
    JSONObject valuejsn = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray tags =valuejsn.getJSONArray("tags");
```

Comment: i get this error:json.JSONException: No value for tags

Comment: can you please post you response?

Comment: JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject( responsestring );
JSONObject resultobject = responseObject.getJSONObject("result");
 JSONArray tagsArray = resultobject.getJSONArray("tags");

Comment: can u edit with the exact function of "showemployee" of my prog pls. coz i could not get the clear idea of yours .pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118836/discussion-between-william-willi-and-ayyappan).

Answer (score 0):

"result" is not a JSONArray, it is a JSONObject.

Try doing:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject result = jsonObject.getJSONObject(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
JSONArray tags = jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_USER_TAGS);
```

Comment: i get :  org.json.JSONException: No value for tags... :(